# Split variable to get the last string as a new variable

Tags: stata

I have a large dataset of `5,000` observations and a subset of my data looks as follows:

```
AandB

1 222 454 213.51  59.15%
444 630 789.46  6.15%
2 374 798 807.69  32.00%
304 738 263.59  19.95%
177 641 617.86  18.07%
857 937 842.27  51.97%
973 127.33  0.03%
86 205 146.62  1.18%
```

I need two variables, `A` and `B` out of this one variable.

For example, `1 222 454 213.51` should be in column `A` as `1222454213.51`and corresponding observation in variable `B` should be `59.15%`
There is a double-space separating what values I want in `A`, and what I want in `B` in the raw data.

Hence, I need:

```
A                    B
1222454213.51     59.15%
444630789.46       6.15%
2374798807.69     32.00%
304738263.59      19.95%
177641617.86      18.07%
857937842.27      51.97%
973127.33          0.03%
86205146.62        1.18%
```

I was able to obtain variable `A` with the following:

```
generate A = reverse(substr(reverse(AandB),strpos(reverse(AandB), "  "), . ))
replace A = subinstr(A, " ", "", .)
```

However, I have trouble extracting the percentage numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to advance is to peel off the last "word" (Stata sense) first:

```
clear 
input str42 AandB 
"1 222 454 213.51  59.15%"
"444 630 789.46  6.15%"
"2 374 798 807.69  32.00%"
"304 738 263.59  19.95%"
"177 641 617.86  18.07%"
"857 937 842.27  51.97%"
"973 127.33  0.03%"
"86 205 146.62  1.18%"
end 

generate B = word(AandB, -1) 
generate A = trim(subinstr(AandB, B, "", .)) 

list AandB A B, separator(0) 

     +------------------------------------------------------+
     |                    AandB                  A        B |
     |------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | 1 222 454 213.51  59.15%   1 222 454 213.51   59.15% |
  2. |    444 630 789.46  6.15%     444 630 789.46    6.15% |
  3. | 2 374 798 807.69  32.00%   2 374 798 807.69   32.00% |
  4. |   304 738 263.59  19.95%     304 738 263.59   19.95% |
  5. |   177 641 617.86  18.07%     177 641 617.86   18.07% |
  6. |   857 937 842.27  51.97%     857 937 842.27   51.97% |
  7. |        973 127.33  0.03%         973 127.33    0.03% |
  8. |     86 205 146.62  1.18%      86 205 146.62    1.18% |
     +------------------------------------------------------+
```

If you do want `A` to be regarded as  specifying some very big numbers, then

```
generate double A2 = real(subinstr(A, " ", "", .))
```

is one way forward. Measuring to 12 significant figures implies that you are in astronomy (and perhaps the first 6 digits are good) or in economics  (and perhaps the first digit is reliable).

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
clear
input str50 AandB
"1 222 454 213.51  59.15%"
"444 630 789.46  6.15%"
"2 374 798 807.69  32.00%"
"304 738 263.59  19.95%"
"177 641 617.86  18.07%"
"857 937 842.27  51.97%"
"973 127.33  0.03%"
"86 205 146.62  1.18%"
end

generate A = subinstr(substr(AandB, 1, strpos(AandB,"%")-6)," ", "", .)
generate B = subinstr(substr(AandB, strpos(AandB,"%")-6, .)," ", "", .)

list, separator(0)

     +---------------------------------------------------+
     |                    AandB               A        B |
     |---------------------------------------------------|
  1. | 1 222 454 213.51  59.15%   1222454213.51   59.15% |
  2. |    444 630 789.46  6.15%    444630789.46    6.15% |
  3. | 2 374 798 807.69  32.00%   2374798807.69   32.00% |
  4. |   304 738 263.59  19.95%    304738263.59   19.95% |
  5. |   177 641 617.86  18.07%    177641617.86   18.07% |
  6. |   857 937 842.27  51.97%    857937842.27   51.97% |
  7. |        973 127.33  0.03%       973127.33    0.03% |
  8. |     86 205 146.62  1.18%     86205146.62    1.18% |
     +---------------------------------------------------+
```

**EDIT:**

On second thought this can be simplified to the following:

```
generate A = subinstr(substr(AandB, 1, strpos(AandB,"  "))," ", "", .)
generate B = subinstr(substr(AandB, strpos(AandB,"  "), .)," ", "", .)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be:

```
split AandB, p("  ")
rename AandB1 A
rename AandB2 B
replace A = subinstr(A, " ", "", .)

list, separator(0)

     +---------------------------------------------------+
     |                    AandB               A        B |
     |---------------------------------------------------|
  1. | 1 222 454 213.51  59.15%   1222454213.51   59.15% |
  2. |    444 630 789.46  6.15%    444630789.46    6.15% |
  3. | 2 374 798 807.69  32.00%   2374798807.69   32.00% |
  4. |   304 738 263.59  19.95%    304738263.59   19.95% |
  5. |   177 641 617.86  18.07%    177641617.86   18.07% |
  6. |   857 937 842.27  51.97%    857937842.27   51.97% |
  7. |        973 127.33  0.03%       973127.33    0.03% |
  8. |     86 205 146.62  1.18%     86205146.62    1.18% |
     +---------------------------------------------------+
```